# IAudioSessionNotification, anyone have working code?

Tags: c++, windows, com, windows-7, audio

I'm picking up some experimental code I was messing with in the Windows 7 Beta now that I've installed the RC.

Basically, I'm trying to get `IAudioSessionManager2` & `IAudioSessionNotification` working together to inform my little app of every new audio session created.

Punchline code in `AudioListener` (public [`IAudioSessionNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370969(VS.85).aspx)):

```
//This is mostly lifted from MSDN
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE AudioListener::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject)
{
    if(riid == __uuidof(IUnknown))
    {
        *ppvObject = (IUnknown*)this;
        return S_OK;
    }

    if(riid == __uuidof(IAudioSessionNotification))
    {
        *ppvObject = (IAudioSessionNotification*)this;
        return S_OK;
    }

    *ppvObject = NULL;

    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

//m_hwnd, and WM_SESSION_CREATED are set to good values
//WM_SESSION_CREATEd via RegisterWindowMessage(...)
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE AudioListener::OnSessionCreated(IAudioSessionControl *pSession)
{
    PostMessage(m_hwnd, WM_SESSION_CREATED, (WPARAM)pSession, 0);

    return S_OK;
}
```

Code registering my listener:

```
BOOL RegisterMonitor(HWND target)
{
    BOOL success = false;

    HRESULT res;
    IMMDevice* pDevice;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator;

    SESSION_LISTENER = NULL;
    SESSION = NULL;

    res = CoInitialize(NULL);

    if(res != S_OK && res != S_FALSE)
        return false;

    SESSION_LISTENER = new AudioListener(target);

    res = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&pEnumerator);
    if(res != S_OK)  goto Exit;

    res = pEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eMultimedia, &pDevice);
    if(res != S_OK)  goto Exit;

    res = pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&SESSION);
    if(res != S_OK)  goto Exit;

    res = SESSION->RegisterSessionNotification(SESSION_LISTENER);
    if(res != S_OK)  goto Exit;

    success = true;

Exit:
    SAFE_RELEASE(pEnumerator);
    SAFE_RELEASE(pDevice);
    if(!success)
    {
        SAFE_RELEASE(SESSION_LISTENER);
        SAFE_RELEASE(SESSION);
    }

    return success;
}
```

`RegisterMonitor(...)` returns true, but no notifications are ever received.  I've been testing by launching little apps with minor sound effects and triggering them (Soltaire, Minesweeper, etc.), confirming that they show up in `SndVol` when I'm expecting to see a notification.

Basically, does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You released the session manager in your `RegisterMonitor` function.  Once you release the last reference to the session manager it is freed and you'll no longer receive session notifications.

Keep the session manager object alive and it should work just fine.

Comment: Where exactly am I freeing the session manager?
Also, even if I comment out all the ->Release()/SAFE_RELEASE() code (leaking COM objects like a sieve) I still do not receive notifications.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the Exit portion - I didn't realize that the session manager was only released on the failure case.

Comment: +1 that a programmer on the Windows Audio stack wrote an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists.  Mad props to Larry for helping random flailing coders though.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue and the solution for me was to add a call to GetSessionEnumerator() after calling RegisterSessionNotification()

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some brief description about why you think this might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nf-audiopolicy-iaudiosessionmanager2-registersessionnotification

[Important]You must call IAudioSessionEnumerator::GetCount to begin receiving notifications. The session enumeration API discards new session notifications until the application has first retrieved the list of existing sessions. This is to prevent a race condition that can occur when a session notification arrives while the application using the session APIs is starting up. Calling GetCount triggers the enumeration API to begin sending session notifications.

I have tried this method, and it is possible to receive the notification

this is my code

```
void RegisterSessionNotification(HWND hWnd)
{
    CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    IAudioSessionManager2* pSessionManager;
    CComPtr<IMMDeviceEnumerator> devices;
    CComPtr<IMMDevice> pEndpoint = NULL;
    CComPtr<IAudioSessionEnumerator> sessions;
    devices.CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator));
    devices->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow::eCapture, ERole::eMultimedia, &pEndpoint);
    pEndpoint->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2), CLSCTX_ALL, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pSessionManager));
    pSessionManager->GetSessionEnumerator(&sessions);
    MyAudioSessionNotificationImp* notification = new MyAudioSessionNotificationImp(hWnd);
    pSessionManager->RegisterSessionNotification(notification);
    int count;
    sessions->GetCount(&count);
}
```