# Implementing Core Audio API events

Tags: delphi, audio, com, delphi-xe5

Trying to implement events for Windows Core Audio API (Win7 64-bit Delphi XE5). My objective is to track the applications in the Volume Mixer to mute audio sessions that are not in my list and to adjust the volume for my target applications.  I successfully enumerate the audio devices and the sessions, mute the audio and adjust the volume on a per-session basis but I am struggling with events.  What I need is to get notified when new sessions are added and when sessions close so that I can enumerate again.  I could use a timer to enumerate the session but I would prefer to avoid that.

The specific events that are not working are `IAudioSessionNotification` and `IMMNotificationClient`.

My questions are follows:

1. Is my approach to deriving classes for events too simplistic?  I
   found an example that is much more involved here:
   [Catch audio sessions events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019865/catch-audio-sessions-events)
   , but it does not seem to work either (not tested personally)
2. Although `IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback` is "working" I think the code
   smells because I am referencing UI elements in the OnNotify function
   so I'd like some feedback/pointers. Is that a valid implementation?

I have two units: uAudioUI which contains the main form and MMDevApi unit that contains Core Audio interface.

The relevant parts of my code current looks like this (its a test app):

```
MMDevApi.pas

...
  IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{657804FA-D6AD-4496-8A60-352752AF4F89}']
    function OnNotify(pNotify:PAUDIO_VOLUME_NOTIFICATION_DATA):HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  PIMMNotificationClient = ^IMMNotificationClient;
  IMMNotificationClient = interface(IUnknown)
  ['{7991EEC9-7E89-4D85-8390-6C703CEC60C0}']
     function OnDefaultDeviceChanged(const flow: EDataFlow; const role: ERole; const pwstrDefaultDevice: LPCWSTR):HRESULT; stdcall;
     function OnDeviceAdded(const pwstrDeviceId: LPCWSTR):HRESULT; stdcall;
     function OnDeviceRemoved(const pwstrDeviceId: LPCWSTR):HRESULT; stdcall;
     function OnDeviceStateChanged(const pwstrDeviceID:LPCWSTR; const dwNewState: DWORD):HRESULT; stdcall;
     function OnPropertyValueChanged(const pwstrDeviceID:LPCWSTR; const key: PROPERTYKEY):HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  IAudioSessionNotification = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{641DD20B-4D41-49CC-ABA3-174B9477BB08}']
      function OnSessionCreated(const NewSession: IAudioSessionControl): HResult; stdcall;
  end;
```

In the main form unit I derive classes for the required interfaces:

```
uAudioUI.pas
...
type

  TEndpointVolumeCallback = class(TInterfacedObject, IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback)
  public
    function OnNotify(pNotify: PAUDIO_VOLUME_NOTIFICATION_DATA): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  TMMNotificationClient = class(TInterfacedObject, IMMNotificationClient)
    function OnDefaultDeviceChanged(const flow: EDataFlow; const role: ERole; const pwstrDefaultDevice: LPCWSTR):HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnDeviceAdded(const pwstrDeviceId: LPCWSTR):HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnDeviceRemoved(const pwstrDeviceId: LPCWSTR):HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnDeviceStateChanged(const pwstrDeviceID:LPCWSTR; const dwNewState: DWORD):HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnPropertyValueChanged(const pwstrDeviceID:LPCWSTR; const key: PROPERTYKEY):HRESULT; stdcall;
  end;

  TAudioMixerSessionCallback = class(TInterfacedObject, IAudioSessionEvents)
    function OnDisplayNameChanged(NewDisplayName:LPCWSTR; EventContext:pGuid):HResult; stdcall;
    function OnIconPathChanged(NewIconPath:LPCWSTR; EventContext:pGuid):HResult; stdcall;
    function OnSimpleVolumeChanged(NewVolume:Single; NewMute:LongBool; EventContext:pGuid):HResult; stdcall;
    function OnChannelVolumeChanged(ChannelCount:uint; NewChannelArray:PSingle; ChangedChannel:uint;
                                EventContext:pGuid):HResult; stdcall;
    function OnGroupingParamChanged(NewGroupingParam, EventContext:pGuid):HResult; stdcall;
    function OnStateChanged(NewState:uint):HResult; stdcall;  // AudioSessionState
    function OnSessionDisconnected(DisconnectReason:uint):HResult; stdcall; // AudioSessionDisconnectReason
  end;

  TAudioSessionCallback = class(TInterfacedObject, IAudioSessionNotification)
    function OnSessionCreated(const NewSession: IAudioSessionControl): HResult; stdcall;
  end;
```

For simplicity I use globals

```
  private
    { Private declarations }  
    FDefaultDevice           : IMMDevice;
    FAudioEndpointVolume     : IAudioEndpointVolume;
    FDeviceEnumerator        : IMMDeviceEnumerator;
    FAudioClient             : IAudioClient;
    FAudioSessionManager     : IAudioSessionManager2;
    FAudioSessionControl     : IAudioSessionControl2;
    FEndpointVolumeCallback  : IAudioEndpointVolumeCallback;
    FAudioSessionEvents      : IAudioSessionEvents;
    FMMNotificationCallback  : IMMNotificationClient;
    FPMMNotificationCallback : PIMMNotificationClient;
    FAudioSessionCallback    : TAudioSessionCallback;
```

...

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  ...
begin
  hr := CoCreateInstance(CLASS_IMMDeviceEnumerator, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, FDeviceEnumerator);
  if hr = ERROR_SUCCESS then
  begin
    hr := FDeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, FDefaultDevice);
    if hr <> ERROR_SUCCESS then Exit;

    //get the master audio endpoint
    hr := FDefaultDevice.Activate(IID_IAudioEndpointVolume, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, nil, IUnknown(FAudioEndpointVolume));
    if hr <> ERROR_SUCCESS then Exit;
    hr := FDefaultDevice.Activate(IID_IAudioClient, CLSCTX_ALL, nil, IUnknown(FAudioClient));
    if hr <> ERROR_SUCCESS then Exit;

    //volume handler
    FEndpointVolumeCallback := TEndpointVolumeCallback.Create;
    if FAudioEndpointVolume.RegisterControlChangeNotify(FEndPointVolumeCallback) = ERROR_SUCCESS then
      FEndpointVolumeCallback._AddRef;

    //device change / ex: cable unplug handler
    FMMNotificationCallback := TMMNotificationClient.Create;
    FPMMNotificationCallback := @FMMNotificationCallback;
    if FDeviceEnumerator.RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(FPCableUnpluggedCallback) = ERROR_SUCCESS then
      FMMNotificationCallback._AddRef;
```

... and then finally, the class functions

```
{ TEndpointVolumeCallback }
function TEndpointVolumeCallback.OnNotify(pNotify: PAUDIO_VOLUME_NOTIFICATION_DATA): HRESULT;
var
  audioLevel : integer;
begin
  //NOTE: this works..
  audioLevel := Round(pNotify.fMasterVolume * 100);
  Form1.trackVolumeLevel.Position := audioLevel;

  if pNotify.bMuted then
  begin
    form1.trackVolumeLevel.Enabled := False; 
    form1.spdMute.Caption := 'X';
  end
  else
  begin
    form1.trackVolumeLevel.Enabled := True; 
    form1.spdMute.Caption := 'O';
  end;

  Result := S_OK;

end;

{ TMMNotificaionClient }
function TMMNotificationClient.OnDefaultDeviceChanged(const flow: EDataFlow; const role: ERole; const pwstrDefaultDevice: LPCWSTR): HRESULT;
begin
  //NOTE: this crashes - referencing a pointer to add 000000000
  Form1.Label2.Caption := 'Audio device changed';
  Result := S_OK;
end;

{ AudioMixerSessionCallback }

function TAudioMixerSessionCallback.OnSimpleVolumeChanged(NewVolume: Single; NewMute: LongBool; EventContext: PGUID): HRESULT;
begin
  //NOTE: This works...
  Form1.trackSessionVolumeLevel.Position := Round(NewVolume * 100);
  Form1.Label2.Caption := EventContext.ToString;
  Result := S_OK;
end;

{ AudioSessionCallback }

function TAudioSessionCallback.OnSessionCreated(const NewSession: IAudioSessionControl): HRESULT;
begin
  //NOTE: This never gets called...
  Form1.Label2.Caption := 'New audio session created';
  Result := S_OK;

end;
```

Comment: Question 2: check with GetCurrentThreadId() if the event occurs in the main thread, if not, you must synchronize().

Comment: @whordaddy, thanks.  GetCurrentThreadId() shows that the even is not running in the main thread. From what I read synchronize() seems to be a bad by design and that PostMessage/SendMessage would be better.

Comment: Regarding Quesion 1, I implemented a class similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858974/iaudiosessionnotification-anyone-have-working-code and same effect; event doesn't get called. What this exercise made me understand though is the value of such a class with PostMessage in the mix. I can store the event data in the class, call PostMessage and then retrieve data from the class in my main thread.

Comment: Lowrider: Thread.Queue() is similar to PostMessage. Use what you like, remember that you need a window handle for PostMessage (which may not always be there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code is a translation from C/C++ ?
When using the TInterfacedObject, you don't need the _AddRef etc. methods, because the TInterfacedObject will handle those.

Another suggestion: I'm missing the threading implementation. Normally this is declared in the constructor or initialization section.

Example:

```
initialization
  CoInitializeEx(Nil,
                 COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
```

or

```
//Create method
  inherited Create(); 
  CoInitializeEx(Nil,
                 COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
```

This is important when using an UI implementation. Otherwise you will not receive any events.
Non UI implementations (like drivers) should use the COINIT_MULTITHREADED model.

Some notes:

Instead of using pointers, like `PGUID`, use `TGUID`. When a field is declared in C++, it could be starting with ie pSingle. In Delphi this should be Single. When C++ is using pointer to pointers (like ppSingle) then - in most cases - in Delphi this would be a PSingle.

Also you declared `function OnChannelVolumeChanged` wrong.

It should be:

```
function OnChannelVolumeChanged(ChannelCount: UINT;
                                NewChannelArray: Array of Single;
                                ChangedChannel: UINT;
                                EventContext: TGUID): HResult; stdcall;
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding but I had put this on hold for a while. The tips in this response helped me find the answer.  The complete answer is that Delphi automatically initializes COM in single threaded mode so I had to uniniitalize the default and then reinitialize with the threaded CoInitializeEx as described above. I then started to receivie the events.